# What does it mean "Property has an invalid value"?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

During the creation of a batch of users in Azure AD by using the Graph API version 1.0 I receive the followiing error message:

```
Property  has an invalid value
```

As you can see, there is not property name in the message, so I can't understand the real problem. What I can say is that those users have no particular conditions among the all others successfully created.

Any ideas?

### Update 1:

As people asked, below are the post data. Since there is sensitive data, I have to changed names and som other personal data:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

And the JSON payload:

```
{
  "accountEnabled": false,
  "country": "BR",
  "displayName": "Jane Sagan",
  "givenName": "Jane",
  "mailNickname": "jane.sagan",
  "otherMails": [
    "jane.sagan.@gmail.com"
  ],
  "passwordProfile": {
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false,
    "password": "J@n3Sa8aN"
  },
  "surname": "Sagan",
  "usageLocation": "BR",
  "userPrincipalName": "jane.sagan@university.br",
  "userType": "Member"
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to share more info? Like the api post body that you are sending?

Comment: Please paste the post body here, then we can try to find out the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property "otherMails" doesn't support the format "jane.sagan.@gmail.com".

Username cannot end with '.' in O365. You can have a try (create a user whose username ends with '.') in O365 portal to verify it.

Comment: Allen is correct. You cannot add aliases ending with '.' in Azure AD. I used your JSON object in my lab and i got the same error. After modifying the other mails attribute, I was able to create the user.

Comment: If my answer is helpful, you can accept it as answer. Thank you.